# Unblocking the getInputStream.read(bytes[])

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, inputstream, serial-communication

I have a java code which runs on Raspberry Pi(RPi) board using Java ME8, the code on RPi communicates with a device using serial communication. The data is exchanged in terms of frames.

While receiving data from the device to Rpi,The getInputStream.read(byte[] byte) blocks and the code gets hanged.And i am unable to implement timeout in the while loop say for example,If i don't rcecive anything for more than 40 sec,it should terminate.

My code is :

```
private void  receivePacket(long timeOut) throws IOException
{
    //timeOut = 120;
    Arrays.fill( awkByte, (byte)0x00 );
    Arrays.fill( rec, (byte)0x00 );
    System.out.println("Receiving");
    i = 0;
    k = 0;

    // initalizes a byte array to receive data

    //awkByte[0] = (byte) 0xFF;


    int num = 0;
    long x = 0;
    x = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis()<=(x+timeOut) )
    {

        Arrays.fill( awkByte, (byte)0x00 );

        num = 0;
        System.out.println("in while");
        k = 0;
        num = connection.getInputStream().read(awkByte);
        if(num <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("num : " + num);
        while(num>0)
        {
            rec[i] = awkByte[k];
            i++;
            k++;
            num--;
        } 

    }

    System.out.println("received : ");

    for(int j = 0 ; j < rec.length ; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(rec[j] + "\t");
    }

}
```

FYI : I am not using any multithreading in my code.

And i am getting less number of bytes than expected and the loop terminates or blockes at read().

Comment: And this is exactly what is specified to happen. Your question?

Answer (score 0):

Check first then read.

```
if (connection.getInputStream().available() > 0) {
    num = connection.getInputStream().read(awkByte);
} else { 
    // do something?
}
```

Comment: connection.getInputStream().available() always returning 0 in my case when data is available or not. It getting blocked on reading method. Kindly anyone having any solution please let me know.